# Using RegExp to match parentheses with set number of characters inside

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression which will match the brackets of `(555)` in `1 (555) 555-5555` and replace the brackets with nothing. However, there should be not match if there is only one parenthesis, such as in this, `1 555)555-5555` or if there is more than three numbers/characters inside the parentheses such as in `(6505552368)`.

My best attempt seemed to be this

```
re = /\((?=.{3})/;
```

But it would only match and replace the first parenthesis, which wasn't much help. Would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Maybe [`s.replace(/\((\d{3})\)/, '$1')`](https://regex101.com/r/K8AUvd/2)? Or, [`s.replace(/^([\d\s]*)\((\d{3})\)/, '$1$2')`](https://regex101.com/r/K8AUvd/1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to remove the first parentheses around 3 digits in the string, you may use

```
s.replace(/\((\d{3})\)/, '$1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K8AUvd/2)

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(` literal symbol
- `(\d{3})` - Group 1 (later referred to with `$1` backreference)
- `\)` - a literal `)`
- `$1`  - a backreference to Group 1.

Or,  if you need to only remove the two parentheses that happen to appear after zero or more digits/whitespaces, use

```
s.replace(/^([\d\s]*)\((\d{3})\)/, '$1$2')
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K8AUvd/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([\d\s]*)`  - Group 1 (later referred to with `$1`): 0+ digits or/and whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(\d{3})`  - Group 2 capturing 3 digits
- `\)` - a literal `)`

Here, `$1$2`, two backreferences are required to restore the texts outside of `(` and `)`.

Comment: This looks way better than my solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best regex but this will work.

> Regex: (?:^|()(\d{3})(?:)|$)

For demo purpose, I have replaced `()` with `_`.

```js
var regex = /(?:^|\()(\d{3})(?:\)|$)/g;
var str = "1 (555) 555-5555 (1234), or (123 or 123)";

console.log(str.replace(regex, "_$1_"))
```

In my understanding, @[Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew)'s answer is better. Still keeping my answer as a reference though.

Comment: Why not just `/\((\d+?)\)/g`?

Comment: Yup. Saw Wiktor's answer and I guess that is better solution. Not sure how much bad this solution is though. I guess I'll keep this answer as an alternate. If you thing this is very bad, feel free to vote. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: ^\d+(\d\d\d)\d+-?\d+$

It accepts a single - sign in the number after the parantheses and only 3 digits inside the parantheses.

Answer (score 0):

I changed little bit Rajesh's solution so every parenthesis will be replaced with nothing.

```
var patt = /\((\d{0,3})\)/g;
var str = '55 (555) 555-(55)55';
console.log(str.replace(patt, "$1"));
```

But it doesn't solve if you need to replace even nested parenthesis. For that purpose you may use this code:

```
var patt = /\((\d{0,3})\)/g;
var str = '55 (5(5)(((5)))) 555-(55)55';
while(str.match(/\((\d{0,3})\)/g))
{
    str = str.replace(patt, "$1");
}
console.log(str);
```

I hope it helps.